# Safe way to use Mongolab and Github.

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mean-stack, mlab

I am wondering the safest way to use Github and Mongolab. I am using the MEAN.JS stack. In the development.js file I want to put:

mongodb://:@ds019068.mlab.com:x

(x being the name of the database).

If I upload my project to github, my username and password would become public to anyone that comes across my github. Is there way to use this set up using a public repository and not share my username and password?

Thank you!

Comment: Put it in a private repo

Answer (score 3):

- Use a different file and then require that file, and do not push that file to keep it private

  ```
  var creds = require(auth.js);
  ```
- Use env variables

  ```
  process.env['VARIABLE'] = 'value';
  ```

  or
- Simply, do not push your credentials to github

Comment: Using environment variables is usually the best approach.